# After latest update for 14.04, cannot log in to any user account

Tags: login, lightdm

I just updated 14.04 to latest patches using the GUI: software update. After that, a restart was required, and now cannot log into any of my accounts. I am sure the passwrds are all correct, it just bounces me back to the same login screen (as opposed to when I really type a bad passwd, then ubuntu states that "Incorrect Passwd"). The only other thing I did was change my background image.

Information from my auth.log:

```
Apr 29 16:00:56 jj-home lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm gnome-keyring-daemon[2449]: couldn't set environment variable in session: The name of the org.gnone.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files gnome-keyring-daemon[2449]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting. lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug with `lightdm`. There are ways to possibly fix it, along with ways of working around the problem. Make sure your computer is connected to the internet and enter a TTY by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. Log in here, then try the following:

1. Purge and reinstall `lightdm`:
   Run `sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm`. Once that's done, run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install lightdm && sudo dpkg --configure lightdm`.
2. Reconfigure `lightdm`:
   I've never had much much luck with this, but you might.
   Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.
3. Install another Display Manager, such as `gdm`:
   Run `sudo apt-get install gdm`.
   When you are asked which Display Manager to use by default, choose `gdm`.

Reboot after all of these.

Comment: When I try to install lightdm, I get the following error: dpkg: error processing package alien (--configure): package alien is not ready for configuration, cannot configure (current state is 'half installed')

Comment: @MartinKenley `Alien`? OK. Try running `sudo apt-get remove --purge alien` and then `sudo apt-get install alien` before the other commands.

Comment: Anyway I continued with the other steps since it said that lightdm was installed.
Now when I rebooted, and choose Ubuntu from Grub menu, I get a black screen. I am using a new Nvidia GTX 960 video card.

Comment: What commands (all of them exactly) did you run?

Comment: sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm. 
sudo apt-get update a
sudo apt-get install lightdm && sudo dpkg --configure lightdm.
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm.
sudo apt-get install gdm.

Comment: OK. In the GRUB menu, choose `Advanced Options for Ubuntu` and choose a Recovery kernel from there. In the next options, choose `root`. Once the prompt comes up, type `mount -o rw,remount /`. Next, run `dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and choose it as the default again.

Comment: OK - passed the black screen. But still in a loop as regards the login. I tried all of these and rebooted, still no luck. 
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow-
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/gshadow
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/gshadow

Check setuid permission for /sbin/unix_chkpwd:
sudo chown root:shadow /sbin/unix_chkpwd
sudo chmod g+s /sbin/unix_chkpwd

Comment: So you're at a login screen now?

Comment: Even `gdm` kicks you back? The login screen should look completely different.

Comment: Sorry - to be clear, I had to change it back to lightdm to get avoid the black screen. If I change to gdm, I continue to get  the black screen. 
Do you think lightdm is causing the loop in the login?

Comment: It is a known `lightdm` bug.

Comment: Sorry, been a long day - will attempt the switch again to gdm. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Once I switch to gdm  using the steps below, ubuntu boots into a black screen. I get the ubuntu splash screen with 4 dots, then black screen. 

In the GRUB menu, choose Advanced Options for Ubuntu and choose a Recovery kernel from there. In the next options, choose root. Once the prompt comes up, type mount -o rw,remount /. Next, run dpkg-reconfigure gdm and choose it as the default again.

Comment: Maybe try kdm or sddm.

Comment: kdm throws me into the same login loop (at login, enter user and pwd) and never gets passed this. Haven't tried sddm yet. I am able to use ctr alt F1 and login at cmd prompt.

Comment: Installing and choosing Xubuntu finally allowed me to get back to a desktop.
Thanks for  helping - the cmds you showed me were and will be very useful.

Comment: Are you OK with Xubuntu?

Comment: Because you can try reinstalling ubuntu-desktop and unity.

Comment: I would prefer to get back to ubuntu / unity. I assume steps are the ones you outlined above for lightdm and gdm? But what is the ubuntu/unity package name?

Comment: I gave them in my comment: purge and reinstall `unity` and `ubuntu-desktop`. It's risky, but you can also try putting a `*` after `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Thanks. I might wait it out since I need it up and running to get work done. Once a patch is rolled out, and I update (while using Xubuntu), will I pick up the patch for lightdm? Or would I have to do something to get the fix?

Comment: This bug has been around for a while, and is caused by a lot of things, so there's no likely fix. Just try the purge and reinstall of the packages. That's perfectly safe.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem after the latest update. I fixed it by disabling the secure boot in the bios .. a few other people have had the same problem.