# Unable to log in to any user account and with different Display Managers

Tags: login, 14.10, lightdm, display-manager

All attempts to log in to my user account, guest, or an account I created to test get instantly thrown back to the login screen. I can log in through tty1 etc.

I have tried deleting .Xauthority and installing new Display Managers, but neither has worked. As per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/616145/408254) I have tried purging lightdm, but it fails every time.

This only started this morning. All I can recall doing yesterday was adding a partition to an empty, secondary drive and playing some dota 2. I can't see how either of which would cause this though. :P

Running Ubuntu 14.10 (64 bit)

Thanks in advance!